# Checking a list member's fields for null in Groovy using closure

Tags: java, groovy, null

```
public class Widget {
    private List<Fizz> fizzes;
    // ... lots of other fields
}

public class Fizz {
    private String boron;
    // ... lots of other fields
}
```

If I have an instance of `Widget`, say, `widget`, how do **(in Groovy, using the `each` closure)** I loop through each of `widget`'s `fizzes` elements and check for the `boron` field being null?

For example, in Java, I might write:

```
Widget widget = new Widget();
for(Fizz fizz : widget.getFizzes())
    if(fizz.getBoron() == null)
        // ... process somehow
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is wrong with what you might write? Assuming `getFizzes()` returns `fizzes` and `getBoron()` returns `boron`, I'm not really seeing the problem here.

Comment: I'm sorry @JoshM (+1) - I updated my answer to be more specific. I'm looking for the clever way of accomplishing this in Groovy using its `each` closure. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`findAll` 'em, and them loop over the result:

```
class Widget {
  List<Fizz> fizzes
}

class Fizz {
  String boron
}

w = new Widget(
  fizzes: [
    new Fizz(boron: 'boron 1'),
    new Fizz(boron: 'boron 2'),
    new Fizz()
  ]
)

nullFizzes = w.fizzes.findAll { it.boron == null }

assert nullFizzes.size() == 1

nullFizzes.each { println it }
```

---

**Update:**

To check no `boron`s are null, use `every`:

```
def everyBoronNotNull = w.fizzes.every { it.boron != null }

assert !everyBoronNotNull
```

Comment: Thanks @Will P (+1) - but where is `it` defined? Is this based into the Groovy language? Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, `it` is an implicit variable passed to the closure. In this situation, it means each item in the collection

Comment: Thanks again @Will P (+1 again): last followup. How could I write a method - using your approach above - that would return true if there were no fizzes with null borons, and false, if at least one fizz contained a null boron?

Comment: Updated my answer. You have `every` and `any` at your disposal. Take a look at [Groovy's default methods](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Object.html).

Answer (score 0):

A nice way to do this in groovy is to filter the list first with `findAll`.  For example:

```
widget.fizzes.findAll { it.boron != null }.each { fizz ->
    // do something with each fizz with non-null boron
}
```

Comment: Thanks @ataylor (+1) - but where is `it` defined, and what is `it`? Thanks again!

Comment: or just `widget.fizzes.findAll{!it.boron}.each{fizz -> ..}`. Every closure has an implicit variable showcasing the contained element in the `delegate`. @TicketMonster

Comment: As dmahapatro says, `it` is the implicit name of the first parameter to a closure.  You could name it yourself: `.findAll { fizz -> fizz.boron != null }`.  Note that `!it.boron` and `it.boron != null` are not *exactly* the same; `!it.boron` will also filter out the empty string.